# PHP SoapClient with Proxy: How to access schema over proxy?

Tags: php, soap, proxy, xsd, soap-client

When initializing the SoapClient class with proxy-options, the WSDL and its methods are accessed over proxy correctly:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    WSDL_URL, 
    array(
        'proxy_host'     => PROXY_HOST,
        'proxy_port'     => PROXY_PORT
    )
);
```

Schemas (schemaLocation) however are not getting accessed over the specified proxy:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/webservice/cisbase" schemaLocation="http://example.com/ws/cis_base.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://de.ws.example" schemaLocation="http://example.com/ws/is_base_de.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This leads to:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from ...

So basically the SoapClient is trying to access the *cis_base.xsd* and *is_base_de.xsd* without proxy which is failing.

Is there a reason why the PHP SoapClient behaves like this and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

In my code i use those options and that works great with our proxy and https protocol. I hope that will work for you to :)

```
        'proxy_host' => PROXY_HOST, 
        'proxy_port' => PROXY_PORT,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer'       => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                )
            )
        )
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, but we have no problems with https. Our problem is that the WSDL schema is accessed without proxy.

Comment: Additionally, you can add `'proxy_login' => PROXY_USER, 'proxy_password' => PROXY_PASS` for the proxy required authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    WSDL_URL, 
    array(
        'proxy_host'     => PROXY_HOST,
        'proxy_port'     => PROXY_PORT,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'proxy' => "tcp://$PROXY_HOST:$PROXY_PORT",
                'request_fulluri' => true,
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

You might want to check other possible parameters in [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php).

Comment: Warning: stream_context_create(): options should have the form [&quot;wrappername&quot;][&quot;optionname&quot;] = $value

Comment: @Ste, try adding protocol wrapper, eg. for HTML: `stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('proxy' => "tcp://$PROXY_HOST:$PROXY_PORT", 'request_fulluri' => true,)))`. See examples in PHP documentation.